# Objective-c calling C function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

Hello i want to call a c Function from an objective c method how can i do that?

here is my function

```
static BOOL test () {

....


if(...){
 return YES;
}else{
 return NO;
}
....
}
```

Comment: have you even tried it before you asked? Obj-C is a superset of C, so all C code is still viable in an Obj-C class/environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as you will in a C program:

```
-(void) myVoidMethod {
    BOOL res;
    res = test();
}
```

Don't forget to declare / include relevant header (again, just like in a C program).

Also, as daknøk mentioned, Objective-C is a strict superset of C, so what works with C - works with Objective-C.

Comment: Worth to note that every single piece of valid C code is valid Objective-C code and does exactly the same thing as in C.

Comment: what do you mean declare header? The c code is in the same file with the method and when i use the above code says "implicit declaration of function test() is invalid in C99"

Comment: @MpampinosHolmens - if it's in the same file then you don't need to declare it. IF you get a specific error, please tell us what it is.

Comment: ok i get a warning when i write the above code in my method i describe it above and i get an error on my function that says "static declaration of test() follows non static declaration "

Comment: Is there any chance you have two declarations/implementations of test, one like this: `static BOOL test ()` and one like this: `BOOL test ()`

Comment: ok solved it i had to put my function above my method, classic C sorry for the mess!

Answer (score 1):

you can call c functions from object-c function in the fallowing way...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  // calling the c function from objective-c function 

    someFunctionName();
}
```

this is my object-c function

```
void someFunctionName()
{
  // write logic what you want in this function...

  int a ,b;
  a=10;
  b=20
 printf("A value is %d \n B value is %d",a,b);


}
```

this is my c function ...